# Yum update fails inside CentOS 7 Docker in the UK, works elsewhere

Tags: docker, centos7, yum

When attempting to run `yum update` inside the stock CentOS 7 Docker container it fails with `One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown)`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it  centos:centos7.8.2003
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * extras: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * updates: mirrors.gethosted.online


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
<snip>
Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base
```

This has started about 2 weeks ago and has happened consistently ever since on a Mac running Docker Desktop in the UK (Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d). Trying the same on a server in Israel running Debian and Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3 is successful, using different mirror hostnames. Also builds on Docker Hub, which use this base image and depend on this command running successfully, work fine.

I tried to follow the suggestion to run `yum --disablerepo` to disable individual repos and it made no difference. How can I get a better insight into what's going wrong, for instance, force Yum to try different mirrors?

Comment: Here's a big clue: "Insufficient space in download directory". Check this out first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue is about yum cache . Yum download package into  cache directory.
Space is not enough in that directory to download header and metadata packages
You must solve space issue ,clear cache and update package info again
Also you can change cache directory to another  ( you have free space)

check cach directory in :

```
cat /etc/yum.conf
```

cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basea

After solve your space issue
run :

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

Comment: Yes, this was a space platform. While my Docker environment was indicating it still had some space, in reality, it didn't have enough.